# Testing classes using System.getProperty(String)

Tags: java, junit

I've written some utility class to use `System.getProperty("user.home")` and in it I added a specific path relative to that one based on `System.getProperty("os.name")`.

What should I do to test my code in all the OS configurations I prepared and perform those tests in a single JUnit test class?

I was thinking about a `SystemPropertyProvider` which would act like Java 8's [`Clock`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) or Guava's [`Stopwatch`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html), but I'm not sure it's the best approach.

Comment: Can you clarify a little? I'm not sure I understand the Clock/Stopwatch analogy. Do you mean that you want to create an abstract class that functions as an alternate to System.getProperty()?

Comment: No, I meant roughly what @artbristol said in his answer. I only was going in too much details in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor the utility class to take a `Properties` via dependency injection. In the main code, give it `System.getProperties()`. In tests, give it your own `Properties` instance with test values.

(Be careful if one of the system properties could change - in that case, you'd need to retrieve a fresh `Properties` each time)

Comment: While I'm not working with DI, I'll definitely use this. I don't know why I completely forgot about `System.getProperties()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the system property and reset if afterwards. You can use the [System Rules](http://www.stefan-birkner.de/system-rules/) library for safely resetting the system property.

Comment: I like this idea and I fully support the idea this project. Only, I prefer to decouple my code from `java.lang.System` completely as I find it much more clear.